# How to import Class in Python

Tags: python, class

I have 2 classes in my main.py and I want to create two more python files to put them in there.
I can't figure out how to import them from those files to my main file. Help!

Here are my classes in main.py:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, k):
        self.key = k
        self.p = None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BST():
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root
```

I was thinking to do something like that:

```
import Node
import BST
```

or

```
from "folderName" import Node
from "folderName" import BST
```

but it didn't work

Comment: use filename instead of foldername

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
from application.app.folder.file import Node
from application.app.folder.file import BST
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine:

```
from fileName import Node
from fileName import BST
```

Notice that you shouldn't use quotation marks